# Не получается подключить OpenCV для android-SDK в Intellij IDEA, gradle

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, opencv, android-gradle

Доброе время суток.
Уже кучу времени мучаюсь с проблемой подключения OpenCV для android в среду Intellij IDEA. Делала все по этой инструкции: https://habr.com/post/262089/. Она для Anroid Studio, но для IDEA я инструкции не нашла. Скачала с офф сайта последнюю версию OpenCV для android, скопировала папку java, добавила библиотеки в jniLibs, прописала зависимость от импортированного модуля. Поменяла циферки с версиями в AndroidManifest у импорт. модуля, но build.gradle -- который в инструкции тоже сказано поменять -- в папке java отсутствовал. 
Скопировала пример из той ссылки (то же самое, что и там):
Activity:

```
 package мой пакет;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import R из моего пакета;


public class ActivityOpenCVTest extends AppCompatActivity

        implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2
{


   private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_opencv_test);
        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.view);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initDebug();
        mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        return inputFrame.rgba();
    }



}
```

Манифест:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="мой пакет"
          android:versionCode = "13"
          android:versionName = "1.5"
        >

    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:anyDensity="true" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-26 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-26 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/..."
            android:label="Мой заголовок"
            android:roundIcon="@drawable/..."
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme = "@style/MyTheme"
            >
        <activity android:name="мой пакет.MainActivity"
                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ... всякие другие активности, включая рассматриваемую ActivityOpenCVTest
    </application>

</manifest>
```

В итоге сборка прошла успешно, но выскочил Warning `"Gradle: module '<этот модуль>' won't be compiled. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java module and Android-gradle module in one project"`. Плюс еще в манифесте импортированного модуля подчеркивается красным `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
а так же android versionCode и versionName

При попытке запустить на устройстве выдаются такие вот ошибки:

```
Error:(8, 26) error: package org.opencv.android does not exist
Error:(9, 26) error: package org.opencv.android does not exist
Error:(10, 23) error: package org.opencv.core does not exist
Error:(16, 40) error: package CameraBridgeViewBase does not exist
Error:(20, 12) error: cannot find symbol class CameraBridgeViewBase
Error:(62, 50) error: package CameraBridgeViewBase does not exist
Error:(62, 12) error: cannot find symbol class Mat
Error:(27, 30) error: cannot find symbol class CameraBridgeViewBase
Error:(46, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable OpenCVLoader
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

Очевидно, что модуль не может подключиться без gradle, но я не знаю, как грамотно сделать gradle-модуль из простого модуля в Intellij IDEA. Или как иначе импортировать библиотеку OpenCV. 
Пожалуйста, помогите решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего вы не импортировали opencv как gradle sub-module. В IDEA это тут: 
File - New - Module from existing source.. Как вариант попробуйте сразу подключить уже собранный модуль например отсюда https://github.com/steveliles/opencv-android

Comment: Спасибо большое, собранный модуль по ссылке заработал.

Comment: Круто, пометьте ответ как решенный.